# How to run multiple commands with Symfony\Component\Process\Process

Tags: laravel, symfony, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

We use a https://www.cloudfoundry.org/ hosting for our app.
To connect to the server we have to use `cf ssh APP-NAME` instead of the normal `ssh` command.

Now I want to write a simple Task runner like https://deployer.org/ to run some artisan commands on the server.
For that I tired `Symfony\Component\Process\Process`, which works for connecting to the server, but I can't keep the connection open to run some other commands.

Does anyone know how to keep the connection open and run some commands?

Here is my current code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process("cf ssh APP-NAME");
$process->setPTY(true);

// Add some other commands like "php artisan migrate" 

$process->run();

echo $process->getOutput();
```

Comment: You're in for a world of hurt if you're looking for sub-processing through the process component. I think it might be possible, but I'd suggest looking into using SSH without the `cf ssh`. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html#application-ssh-access-without-cf-cli  Vasyl's suggestion of laravelcollective/remote is spot-on IF you can figure out how to connect via pure SSH. If you can't, rather than a bunch of sub-processes, put all the commands you want to sub-process (artisan migrate, etc...) inside a task: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/using-tasks.html

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer.
I will check that, when it works with pure ssh i can use deployer for my tasks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing commands on a remote server is a totally different feature that starting subprocesses. So it does not belong to the Process component but to another library. 
Try to use this one [phpseclib/phpseclib](https://packagist.org/packages/phpseclib/phpseclib) here you can find nice manual [phpseclib/phpseclib manual](https://www.sitepoint.com/phpseclib-securely-communicating-with-remote-servers-via-php/).

Or this one [ssh-client/ssh-client](https://packagist.org/packages/ssh-client/ssh-client).

Also, take a look at this laravel package [laravelcollective/remote](https://packagist.org/packages/laravelcollective/remote)